# How do I shorten the current directory path shown on terminal?

Tags: linux, files, terminal, directory

If I am in a deep directory, let's say:

```
~/Desktop/Dropbox/School/2017/C/A3/
```

then when I open up terminal, it says

```
bob@bob-ubuntu:~/Desktop/Dropbox/School/2017/C/A3/$
```

and then I write my command.
That is very long, and every line I write in the terminal goes to the next line. I want to know if there's a way so that it only displays my current directory. I want it to display:

```
bob@bob-ubuntu: A3/$
```

This way it's much clear, and always I can do `pwd` to see my entire directory. I just don't want the entire directory visible in terminal because it takes too much space.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to modify `PS1` in your shell startup file (probably `.bashrc`).

If it's there already, its setting will contain `\w`, which is what gives your working directory. Change that to `\W` (upper case). The line in `bashrc` file looks like below:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Log out and in again, or do:

```
. .bashrc
```

or (you need to add this prefix '~/' if you are in others directory)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

(or whatever your file is).

If it isn't there, add something like:

```
PS1='\u@\h: \W:\$'
```

to `.bashrc` or whatever. Look up `PS1` in the `bash` manual page to get more ideas.

Be careful; `bash` can use several more than one initialisation file, e.g. `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`; it may be that `PS1` is set in a system-wide one. But you can override that in one of your own files.

Comment: "if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ ' fi;" the command only applies after the "fi;" to terminate the IF or else becomes incomplete. For me in ubuntu 22.04 "PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '" works fine without issues.

Answer (score 131):

Since bash 4, to shorten the depth of directory in command-line is done by using `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` in the `.bashrc` file. Just remember to reopen your terminal.

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1
```

See the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PROMPT_005fDIRTRIM) for more information.

**Example**

`bob@bob-ubuntu:~/Desktop/Dropbox/School/2017/C/A3/$`

will be trimmed to

`bob@bob-ubuntu:.../A3/$`

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Setting something like `export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` in your `.bashrc` is the perfect middle ground between `\W` and `\w`. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect.

Comment: @spkane, there's no need to `export` that to child processes.  Just set it as a shell variable, as shown.

Comment: This is great, can be also a higher number to see more like `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3`. But my question is **Is there also the starting section settings? So the result is something like `/media/user/..../endDir1/endDir2`** ? (specifically without editing PS1 in bashrc or at all directly...)

Answer (score 6):

This is portable to all `sh` shells.

Assign to `PS1` in one of your shell startup files:

```
PS1='${PWD##*/} $ '
```

The prompt will look like

```
dir $
```

Where `dir` is the base name of the current directory.

The `$PWD` variable contains the current directory path, and `${PWD##*/}` will strip the everything up to and including the last `/` in that path.

The single quotes prevents the shell form evaluating the variable substitution at the time of assignment (the value of `$PS1` will be evaluated each time the prompt is displayed).

The `PS1` variable should not be exported as it's only used by the current shell.

Comment: This worked for WSL 2.0 like a charm. I just put in my bashrc and be done with it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using bash, change the prompt string (variable PS1) so that it has `\W` instead of `\w`.

e.g. if your PS1 is currently `\u@\h:\w\$`, set it to `\u@\h:\W\$`

To make this permanent, you will have to change it in your bash startup files - e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

see `man bash` and search for `PROMPTING` for full details and a list of backslash-escaped special characters.

Comment: I have 4 mentions of PS1
Do I change all 4?

Comment: 4 mentions where? in ~/.bash_profile?    it should do no harm to change all instances of `\w` in PS1 to `\W`.  or you could just set the prompt to whatever you like at the bottom of the script.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh` prompt strings, `%~` expands to the current working directory with things like `$HOME` changed to `~` or `/home/user` to `~user` like in `tcsh`, but you can change it to `%2~` to limit it to the last 2 components of that path for instance:

```
$ PS1='%n@%m:%2~$ '
me@here:~/bin$ cd /usr/local/share/man/man1
me@here:man/man1$
```

Or you can use `%20<…<%~%<<` to ensure the expansion of `%~` is not wider than 20 columns and display that `…` to indicate the truncation if any:

```
me@here:man/man1$ PS1='%n@%m:%20<…<%~%<<$ '
me@here:…ocal/share/man/man1$
```

Comment: Very helpful for zsh since PROMPT_DIRTRIM export doesn't work in .zshrc file

Comment: @Arsal, yes  `$PROMPT_DIRTRIM` is bash specific, and is also a weird design  to choose to have a shell variable to control one prompt expansion  (also poor choice to use backslash for prompt expansion which is already  way overloaded when csh had been using `%` for decades beforehand, and bash had already copied many features from csh). In any case, you don't want to export that variable  there, that would be unnecessary environment pollution.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you will have to edit **PS1** ,

insted of `\w` , you will have a command or a variable that shows shortned path :

original PS1

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

change it to

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]${PWD##*/}\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

Note this will put the username insteed of ~ if you are in your home dir !

to avoid that you will need a few commands insteed of ${PWD##*/} e.g.

```
if [[ "${PWD}" == "${HOME}" ]] ; then printf \~; else echo -n ${PWD##*/}; fi
```

the new PS1 will look like the following

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]`if [[ "${PWD}" == "${HOME}" ]] ; then printf \~; else echo -n ${PWD##*/}; fi`\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

**oOps** 
while i am trying to save the world i had noIdea|forgoten the **\W**

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chrissound/SodiumSierraStrawberry

Allows you to truncate a path like:

> From:
>   /home/sodium/Projects/Personal/Sierra/Super/Long/Path/HolyAvacado
>
> To: »Projects/Sie…/Sup…/Lon…/Pat…/HolyAvacado/

Answer (score 0):

just enter:

```
PS1='\u:\W\$ '
```

and press Enter

Comment: You might explain that this setting will go away each time they exit the shell, and consider improving your post to describe how to set it permanently. You could also describe what the syntax is doing, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

add this to end of bashrc
then you type short, it will reduce length on demand :), Thanks
@Esmaeil MIRZAEE

````bash
short(){
 if [[ $PROMPT_DIRTRIM -eq 0 ]]; then
    PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
 else
    PROMPT_DIRTRIM=
 fi 
}```
````